# Can eclipse debug or run two program in a project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Can eclipse debug run two program in a project? I mean I have two program with `public static void main()` method. Is that OK to debug them at the same time? I have tried to do that. There are two display console. There are two threads in debug window. You can click the thread to decide which program you wanna debug. But the result to run or debug program in this way seems different with run or debug them seperately? Does any one has similar experience?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run and debug two or more java programs at the same time in eclipse without them influencing with each other. In fact you can run and debug the same main method multiple times at once without problems. The reason for this is that each time you click run or debug, a new jvm instance is created, and the current set of class files is loaded. The caveat to this is that if both programs rely on some shared resource, they can influence each other indirectly. Without seeing your code, it is hard to say for sure why you get different results when you run multiple programs simultaneously.

Comment: I am trying to dynamically modify class which already loaded in jvm. At first, run the target program and it starts a jvm(for example, jvm1). And then run another program to attach the agent to jvm1 to modify class loaded in jvm1, and it starts jvm2. Anyway, If I run these two program in eclipse in one projcet, I got `retransformClasses()` to be run twice and get on error(`class redefinition failed`) at the second time to call it. But if I run target program in windows command window, and another in eclipse. I got nothing. There should not be difference. They use same jre.

Comment: Bit outside my area, but when running in debug mode eclipse will attach it's own debugging agent using the -agentlib flag. If you ran the program from command line it wouldn't do this obviously. This might be the cause of your problems? If you want to see the exact java command used by eclipse to run your program, use process explorer in windows or something similar in linux. Then you can compare that with how you run it at command line.

Comment: Did you mean eclipse attach an agent by default, even though I did not add any debug parameter by hand?

Comment: If you use debug mode, the javaw.exe command that eclipse issues will look like this: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:61428 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath ... etc. I assume that eclipse then attaches it's debugger to that address.