# Sharing resources while simultaneously running multiple classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency

I am currently developing a big java project using Eclipse and would like to run two independent classes (each with a min method) at the same time. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453894/run-two-java-programs-from-eclipse-at-once) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609133/can-eclipse-debug-or-run-two-program-in-a-project) and this seems easily doable. My main questions/concerns are: how will Eclipse handle shared resources? and would resource sharing affect the output of the classes? My classes share same data folders and files, use same jars, and they create objects from same other classes and I am worried that this might affect the sanity of the output of each when ran simultaneously.

Here is my setting:

- Same workspace
- Same project
- Running Eclipse Juno

Any reading recommendations on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two separate programs running at once, they will remain separate and won't interfere internally with one another.

If they're reading/writing files however, they might end up stepping on each others toes while doing so. Where it's important to ensure only one program has access to a certain directory at once, you'll have to implement your own locking mechanism to ensure that each program knows that the other is currently doing stuff in the given directory.

Note that eclipse mostly has nothing to do with the running programs - it launches them and manages console io etc, but resource-wise they can be considered the responsibility of the OS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding is reading from shared resources should be fine since none of the programs are altering the shared data, so why would I need a locking mechanism in this case?

Comment: In the case of only reading you are correct, nothing extra required.